# Result Activity from Plugin thread

Tags: java, android, android-activity, plugins, start-activity

I am on a simple plugin thread in android. I would like to create an activity which does certain tasks and gives the result to the thread back. I have the plugin context and using this I can get the Application Context.

For this, I was pondering over the use of startActivityForResult() and then getting the callback using the onActivityResult(). The problem with this is that onActivityResult() is defined in the Activity class and my plugin doesn't extend Activty.

Using BroadcastReciever is an option but I would like to know if there is anything else.

What is the best approach to go with?